# UTF-8 not working on some Android devices

Tags: css, encoding, android

We have recently launched a humble website, powered by Wordpress. And now, some of our users complain that certain Swedish special characters do not display properly. As far as I know, this has only happened on Android, but regardless of broswer. But I have been unable to reproduce this on my desktop PC as well as my Android device (both 4.2 and 4.4).

I have tried to set the first line of the CSS editor to:

```
@charset  "UTF-8";
```

But can't verify that this works. Any tips on how I reproduce this?

And should I look into other alternatives, instead of the CSS editor? When I view the source of the start page, I see the following in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In case the question is more easily answered through a visit, the site is http://www.slutet.nu

Comment: Looks OK in the native browser on my Android 4.1.2, but not on my desktop (Windows 7, Firefox).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, if a bit puzzling :) It looks alright in Firefox 28 on my Windows 7 machine. And I don't think I have changed any default settings. I don't understand how this can be :)

Comment: You might have a sans-serif font set as default font in Firefox; this could explain why the font difference is not as prominent as with Open Sans vs. a normal default serif font.

Comment: My default in Firefox is Times New Roman...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 is not the problem, the font **Open Sans** is it. The character sub-set you use doesn’t contain all needed glyphs, so the browser has to get the missing glyphs from other fonts. Android and some older desktop browsers aren’t very good with *glyph substitution*, so that might fail.

Remove Open Sans, use a system font, and you are fine. Or use  an extended set of Open Sans, which contains all needed glyphs. This will never be complete, because you cannot know which fonts are needed for an automatic translation.

Comment: Normal Open Sans, as distributed by Google, contains Scandinavian letters (and all of Latin 1), so they should be always available—unless you are using a somehow broken copy of Open Sans.

Comment: toscho: Thank you, I will look into this right away (though, without being able to determine when and if this is working). @JukkaK.Korpela: Thanks, I will see if there could be something wrong with my particular Open Sans, which does sound a bit weird.

Comment: The version used on that site comes directly from the theme. It is probably different than the Google version. While local versions are better in terms of privacy, they must be tested too. :)

Comment: It seems forcing the theme to pick the Google font with the same name resolved the issue. Many thanks!